# select data from 2 table with where condition in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to check column status1 from 'studData' and status2 from 'studData1' where status1   &status2= 'Incomplete'.

I have 2 table @StudData , @StudData1

```
Studdata
```

userid  fname    lname    mname  status1
   rswani suresh   pqr      lmn    complete
    root  abc               pqr    incomplete

```
Studdata
```

userid   occupation  age  hobbies   status2
  rswani    student     22   reading   complete
  root      service     21             Incomplete

I want to select fname,lname,mname from studdata where stauts1 & status 2 = 'incomplete'

I tried

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("select s.userid,s.fname,s.lname,s.last_exam_passed,s.course_name, s.status1, d.status2 from StudData s INNER JOIN StudData d ON s.status1= d.status2 " , con);
```

I am unable to select data which are incomplete from 2 table

Comment: How the tables are related to each other? I am asking about primary key and foreign key.

Comment: Yes I use here primary key and foregin key function

Comment: Which are they? I mean, any `id` fields?

Comment: hi @Dipika! Please add full table structure atleast the PrimaryKey of each table? Are these two tables with name StudData & StudData1? becoz  in query u used both StudData with different alias names so asked

Comment: userid ....but I dont want to take userid in query

Comment: Do both tables contain userid? Can you show the structure of each table? Even if you don't want it to be selected.

Comment: yup both contain same userid...its primary key

Comment: `select s.userid,s.fname,s.lname,s.last_exam_passed,s.course_name, s.status1, d.status2 from StudData s INNER JOIN StudData d ON s.userid= d.userid and s.status1 = u.status2 where s.status1 = 'Incomplete'`

Comment: Thank Roopesh. Is it able to check Incomplete status from both table?

Comment: @Dipika: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the tables with the relationship (PK & FK) and use `WHERE` clause to check the fields `status` and `status1`.

Here `userid` is the relationship between two tables, so try this:

```
SELECT s.userid,s.fname,s.lname,s.last_exam_passed,s.course_name, s.status1, d.status2 
FROM StudData s INNER JOIN 
     StudData d ON s.userid= d.userid
WHERE s.status='incomplete'
AND d.status1='incomplete'
```